# Average degree of finite components in a network

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a network with a giant component and some finite component. I need to compute the average degree of the finite component (without the giant component).
To do this I try to remove the giant component from the list of all components and create a subgraph of the reining components

```
  components = nx.connected_components(G) #list of all the components
  GC = max(components, key=len )  #giant component
  finite_cluster= components.remove(max(components, key=len )) #remove the GC from the components
  subgraph_finite_cluster= G.subgraph(finite_cluster)
```

but I receive an error for the subgraph.

I also try to remove the part of the subgraph

```
  components = nx.connected_components(G) #list of all the components
  GC = max(components, key=len )  #giant component
  finite_cluster= components.remove(max(components, key=len )) #remove the GC from the components
```

In this case the error is

```
'generator' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

So how can I separate the finite components from the giant component?

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that `nx.connected_components` returns a *generator* for the components, *not* a list of components.  This is a close cousin of `range`.  For instance, `range(10)` does not return a list of integers 0-9; it returns an iterator that will return the integers 0-9 on ten successive calls.

Your repair should be simple: collect the generator outputs into a list with

```
components = list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

Since you neglected to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE), I can't test this in place for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the components by length and take the slice that excludes the GCC:

```
finite_cluster = sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)[:-1]
```

Note: naturally, this works if you have only one GCC.